# trying to achieve some effect on the background when page scrolling

Tags: javascript, angular, types

I'm trying to achieve this effect here in the header, that make the background go up and down when scrolling
here is the example

https://frix.themes95.com/

here what I've tried

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yzx998?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

it almost does the required but there is something goes wrong when I'm trying to scroll up

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting to set your `lastScrollTop` variable after each scroll event, so it always thinks you're scrolling down. Just put `this.lastScrollTop = st;` as your last line in the `onScroll` function like this:

```js
onScroll(event) {
    const st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if (st > this.lastScrollTop) {

      this.pxToMove -= 3;
      this.background.nativeElement.style.transform = `translateY(${this.pxToMove}px)`;
    } else {
      this.pxToMove += 3;
      this.background.nativeElement.style.transform = `translateY(${this.pxToMove}px)`;

    }
    this.lastScrollTop = st;
  }
```

Here's a way to condense this function and have it change position based on how far you've scrolled.

```js
onScroll(event) {
    const st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    // Move the image by the difference between the old and new scrollTop
    this.pxToMove -= (st-this.lastScrollTop);
    this.background.nativeElement.style.transform = `translateY(${this.pxToMove}px)`;
    // Set the previous scrollTop
    this.lastScrollTop = st;
  }
```

Comment: still same problem when I scroll fast

Comment: The problem from scrolling fast comes from the fact that you only move the image by 3 pixels no matter how far you've scrolled. You can instead use the difference between `lastScrollTop` and `st` to change the offset, in fact that would make the entire thing a little bit shorter as you wouldn't need to check if you've scrolled up or down, I'll update my answer in a second to demonstrate this.

Comment: @khaledmahmoud I updated the answer, it's the second piece of code there now